# im having difficulty getting downloaded json response into my data model and accessing it in code

Tags: variables, swiftui, datamodel, jsondecoder

i have the following code in which i'm trying to download exchange rates into my app to use in currency conversion.
The data fetch seems to work ok, as does the json decoding model, but i'm unable to get the data through the Rates variable

```
import SwiftUI
struct ExchangeRates: Codable {
    var conversionRates: [String: Double]?
    
    init(conversionRates:[String:Double]) {
        
        self.conversionRates = conversionRates
    }
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case conversionRates = "conversion_rates"
    }
}

class DownloadingData:ObservableObject{
    
    @Published var Rates:ExchangeRates = ExchangeRates.init(conversionRates: ["test" : 0])
    
    init() {
        datatask()
    }
    
    func datatask() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://v6.exchangerate-api.com/v6/********************/latest/GBP") else {return}
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url){(data,response,error) in
            
            guard let data = data else {
                print("no data")
                return
            }
            guard error == nil else {
                print("error :\(String(describing: error))")
                return
            }
            guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
                print("invalid response")
                return
            }
            guard response.statusCode >= 200 && response.statusCode < 300 else {
                print("status code should be 2xx, but is \(response.statusCode)")
                return
            }
            guard let rates = try? JSONDecoder().decode(ExchangeRates.self, from: data) else {return}
            print(rates) **// this works and prints out data**
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                [weak self] in
                self?.Rates = rates
                print(self?.Rates) **// this works and prints out the data**
            }
            print(self.Rates) **// this doesnt print out anything**
        }.resume()
        print(Rates) **// this doesnt print out anything**
    }
}
```

i can't seem to get the data into the Rates Variable
any guidance please

thanks

here is a sample of the console output :

ExchangeRates(conversionRates: Optional(["test": 0.0]))
Optional(test3.ExchangeRates(conversionRates: Optional(["BZD": 2.7002, "PHP": 68.7948, "PGK": 4.725, "BND": 1.8176, "HNL": 32.8885, "TND": 3.7553, "BDT": 115.2218, "SBD": 10.6866, "NIO": 47.4824, "XDR": 0.963, "IDR": 19213.9064, "XCD": 3.6453, "CAD": 1.7152, "UGX": 4778.6135,])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try this, using your `ExchangeRates` struct:

```
class DownloadingData: ObservableObject{
    @Published var rates = ExchangeRates(conversionRates: ["test" : 0])
    
    init() {
        datatask()
    }
    
    func datatask() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://v6.exchangerate-api.com/v6/********************/latest/GBP") else {return}
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url){(data,response,error) in
            
            guard let data = data else {
                print("no data")
                return
            }
            guard error == nil else {
                print("error :\(error)")
                return
            }
            guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
                print("invalid response")
                return
            }
            guard response.statusCode >= 200 && response.statusCode < 300 else {
                print("status code should be 2xx, but is \(response.statusCode)")
                return
            }
            guard let exRates = try? JSONDecoder().decode(ExchangeRates.self, from: data) else {return}
            print(exRates)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.rates = exRates   // <--- here
                print(self.rates)     // <--- here
            }
            // print(self.rates) // <--- NEVER here
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

EDIT-1: with completion closure:

```
class DownloadingData: ObservableObject{
    @Published var rates = ExchangeRates(conversionRates: ["test" : 0])
    
    init() {
        datatask() { isDone in
            print(self.rates) // <--- here OK
        }
    }
    
    func datatask(completion: @escaping(Bool) -> ()) {   // <--- here 
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://v6.exchangerate-api.com/v6/********************/latest/GBP") else {return}
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url){(data,response,error) in
            
            guard let data = data else {
                print("no data")
                return
            }
            guard error == nil else {
                print("error :\(error)")
                return
            }
            guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
                print("invalid response")
                return
            }
            guard response.statusCode >= 200 && response.statusCode < 300 else {
                print("status code should be 2xx, but is \(response.statusCode)")
                return
            }
            guard let exRates = try? JSONDecoder().decode(ExchangeRates.self, from: data) else {return}
            print(exRates)   // <--- here OK
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.rates = exRates
                print(self.rates)     // <--- here OK
                completion(true)      // <--- here return completion
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: yes both these print statements work, however when i try to print or access rates after .resume outside of this function, the variable is empty or blank

Comment: yes, that is expected. You are using an async function, this means you need to "wait" until it has finished before you can print its results.

Comment: updated my answer with using completion closure, to tell you when your `datatask()` is done.

Comment: well this works, but can you explain to me why rates is not accessible elsewhere in the class. i need to take a value from rates for a currency and do some maths with it, and then also pass that value along later as another published variable

Comment: `rates` is accessible everywhere in the class. But since you get the data 
asynchronously, you have to "wait" until is has finished the fetching 
to access the fetched data. This is why we have a closure. 
If you use it before that, `rates` will have just the 
conversionRates `["test" : 0]` in it. 
With regards to calculations and passing values, since you are using an `ObservableObject` 
there should be no problems at all.

Answer (score 1):

Declare `rates`  – please with starting lowercase letter –  as empty dictionary

```
@Published var rates = [String:Double]()
```

In the struct delete the init method and declare the dictionary also non-optional

```
struct ExchangeRates: Decodable {
    let conversionRates: [String: Double]
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case conversionRates = "conversion_rates"
    }
}
```

in the `DispatchQueue` closure assign the value of `conversionRates` to `rates`

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { // no weak self needed
    self.rates = rates.conversionRates
}
```

In the view enumerate the dictionary `rates`

Comment: hi vadian, ive made the changes you suggest but its not worked for me. rates is still not accessible or is empty

Comment: try this: `DispatchQueue.main.async {  if let convrt = rates.conversionRates { self.rates = convrt } print(self.rates)}`. Do not use `print(self.rates)` outside the `DispatchQueue`

Comment: that gives me this error : Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '[String : Double]'

Comment: Outside of the closure the rates are not accessible but when you create a `@StateObject` in the view you get notified on any change of `rates`